# Reformat output of numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

The following code

```
arr_0 = numpy.zeros((3,3))
arr_0[(0,0)] = 1
ind = numpy.where(arr_0 == 0)
print(ind)
```

gives the following output

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

The output is a list of x's and then a list of y's, and I would like a list of tuples (x,y), something like:
    [[0,1],[0,2], ...].
How can I do that ?

Comment: A list of tuples? Or a numpy matrix?

Comment: Maybe, the idea is to be able to select a tuple (x,y) randomly from the output.

Comment: Use `list(zip(*ind))`.

Comment: Ok, so the term is "merge lists".

Comment: Yes, that seems like the most common term for this (among pair up, combine, paste together, pairwise append, etc.). :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2407398?page=1&sort=hot

Comment: Try `np.transpose(ind)`.  Or `np.argwhere(...)`, which does the same thing.